# java code to connect to kepware opc ua server

Tags: java, server, opc-ua

I am looking for a way to communicate java with the Kepware OPC Server. I want Java program to read Kepware OPC Server tags. Can anyone give some suggestions on how to achieve this.Also what will be the mode of authentication here is it certificate based or username password based.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at using an OPC UA SDK like [Eclipse Milo](https://github.com/eclipse/milo)?

You could get started by modifying one of the read examples to point at Kepware instead.

Comment: Am not sure if it supports alarm and event data any idea if it does?My requirement is to read data from kepserver which inturn will be reading OPC-DA and OPC-AE data from a PLC.

Comment: Yes, you can subscribe to alarms and events with the Milo client SDK. I'm not sure if Kepware actually has support for that though.

Comment: great that should help me with the implementation now,Thanks.Kepware doesnt support pulling OPC-AE data from plc but i can generate Alarms on the DA data by using alarm and events plug in kepware.